# Not found hover cufon

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover, cufon

I have a problem with Cufon, I have a list with a source that I have, but also put the hover quisiea other source, it is possible?

```
Cufon.replace('header nav#menu ul li', {fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'});
Cufon('header nav#menu ul li a', {
    hover: {
        fontFamily:'Archer Bold'
    }
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykbxm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, lets say that there is cufon api: [CUFON API](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API)

Everything is writen here, but no good examples, so if you want to use cufon hover on some elements, first you have them active. There is some elements whitch is allery activated, but I don't remember which. For example a element:

`hoverables: { a: true }`

Full example you can find: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GomatoX/ykbxm/6/)

P.S. It's bad decision to call cufon for same element twice: you was calling cufon for li and then for a element.

Comment: I have a question, as does work because I have 4 sources (fonts) distinas and I see you removed that and does not work very well: (

Comment: Can you improove your question?, because I can't understand it.